# inflection point with third derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inflection-point

> **Problem**: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f'''(x)<0$ for every $x\not=0$ and $f''(0)=0$. Prove that $M(0,f(0))$ is an inflection point of $f$.

I use the following definition of inflection points:

*Dfn: Let $f:(\alpha,\beta)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differentiable in $(\alpha,\beta)-\{x_0\}$ that is continuous (but not necessarily differentiable) at $x_0$. If $f$ is concave up at $(\alpha,x_0)$ and concave down at $(x_0,\beta)$ or vice versa
**and** the curve of $f$ admits a tangent line at $(x_0,f(x_0))$, then $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is an inflection point of $f$.*

**Attempt**: the result follows immediately with the additional assumption that $f''$ is continous at $x=0$.

Comment: @Surb How can we write $f'''(0)$? $f$ is three times differentiable at $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$

Comment: sorry, I thought it was written $f'''(0)<0$. But the argue is more or less the same. **Hint** Since $f'''(x)<0$ for all $x\neq 0$, $f''$ is decreasing for all $x\neq 0$. In particular, $f''(x)>0$ for all $x<0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x>0$. Therefore $f'$ has a maximum at $x=0$....

Comment: @Surb I can see that $f''$ is decreasing at $(\infty,0)$ and$(0,+\infty)$ but how can we show that it is decreasing for all $x\not=0$ ?

Comment: acctually, saying that $f''$ is decreasing for all $x\neq 0$ is useless. Since $f''$ is continuous, you can directly say that $f''$ is decreasing on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Surb but $f''$ is not continous at $x=0$ ... at least I do not see that

Comment: If the condition $f \in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)\cap\mathcal C^3(\mathbb R-\{0\})$ is not satisfy, the exercice is wrong...

Comment: @Surb is there any counterexample?